# keras custom loss and backend functions

Tags: keras, loss

I hope to use numpy for calculating loss. So as a starter I tried the code below which I thought it should not change any. However, the loss negatively grows. Does anyone know why?

```
def mySSE2(y_true, y_pred):
try:
    print '1+++++++++++++'
    e = y_true -  y_pred
    mse = K.mean(K.square(e))  # this just mse
    mse = K.variable(K.eval(mse))) # this is my test
    result3 = mse
except:
    print '================'
    return e

return result3
```

Comment: Why are you using K.eval? That's not necessary.

Comment: Correct it is not necessary. I'm trying to test if numpy to tensor conversion is properly done because I have complex loss calculation in numpy and convert it into tensor.

Comment: Your loss is just returning the difference between y_true and y_pred, its not the mean squared error at all.

Comment: That probably true. What'd be causing try statement fail? K.eval? Anyways, can there be a way, I cacluate the loss in numpy and return for Keras? It looks Keras doesn't like return value in numpy.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "try statement fail". You cannot compute a loss in numpy, as Keras needs to compute gradients and that is only possible if you use keras.backend functions.

Comment: Since you said my loss is just returning the difference not mse. I assumed that's only possible when the "try" block fails because the "except" block is returning the e, which is the difference.  If this is not what you meant, would you explain why it returns only the difference? I thought "result3" is being returned.